# Session management in multiple websites

Tags: reactjs

I have three react folders and a single express login API which talks to a MySQL database. And one of them I coded with a route to a login page. Below is the example of one of the route of my React project. (Other projects are currently not connected to this route since they are in a different folder)

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<App />}></Route>
            <Route path='/login' element={<Accounts />}></Route>
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

The problem is I want the functionality of the login page to all of my React folders without copying the login page in each folder. Do I need to store something in the database to get their session? Or is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Comment: can you explain more because its hard to understand what you want to achieve here

Comment: Do you want to retain login detail after login to access other protected route?

Comment: I just want my login page to be portable. I want to access the Accounts component (login) inside the other folders.

Comment: @kennarddh It would be best if I could retain my login details in all folders but my main priority is to use the login component in other folders. I think it will be hard to retain the login details since all three folders are run in different ports.

Comment: You have multiple react app in one folder?

Comment: yes I have multiple react apps in one folder

Comment: https://dev.to/kleeut/how-do-you-share-authentication-in-micro-frontends-5glc?